# Background image with "buttons" made from other images

Tags: html, button, background, overlay

I'm making a pretty simple html page for Facebook, I want a big image as the background and little images as buttons all over the bg, I want to know how can I code the background and the "buttons" so these take you to a different page.

Comment: Try something first, then post your doubts here.

Answer (score 0):

For buttons you just need to create the element, and then add in the link attribute.

So for creating a button that links to Google.com:

```
<button onclick="location.href='http://www.example.com'"> www.example.com</button>
```

Often people will have a div that contains that majority of their body of their html. So you can use:

```
background-image : url('image.jpg');
```

attached to your `div` or `body` tag.

A similar more thorough approach would be to just attach it to your `html` selector, like so:

```
html { 
  background: url(image.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

I've made a **[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/3rACM/)** to give you an example of how to use background-image, and a button that links to Google.

You can of course style any of these elements.